# Why canoe display error frame ID's message?

Tags: canoe

I am automotive software engineer.

I use vector Canoe tool to simulation can network.

For example, at Ecu sleep status in vehicle, I transmitted general message to Ecu  having IG Block function in Canoe. After that, Ecu was wake up.but tx error frame generated. I saw Error frame information. It was message's id I sent.  And, after 1ms time, message of same Id transmitted in canoe. I guess can controller may transmit error frame because of message to send uses IG Block. And I think that Can controller should not receive message. And I think IG block message was lost.But in Canoe display, seems to transmit error frame and normal message. Is it true? Can controller know whather or not Normal message ?
And can controller receive that message?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yac3k.png)

Comment: Without at least a screenshot of the trace window, helping here will be very difficult.

Comment: Thanks to reply M.Spiller. Soon I will upload a screenshot. Then I waiting for your help

Comment: @M.Spiler I uploaded Canoe Log Screen. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, you can see, that the error frame is caused by a bit error.

Bit error means, that the message observed on the bus during sending did not match the message sent. It is a Tx error, i.e. the sender itself detects and alerts the error, and will try again.

Bit errors are caused mostly by wiring problems, e.g. wires too long for the used baud rate, bus not terminated correctly, etc.
It may also be that the baudrate is not setup correctly.

I hope that helps you to find the root cause.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I'm sorry but I have a question. I think that a CAN Controller may send a error frame. is it true ? And Canoe H/W Interface will send message(0x3D) using IG Block. is it true? after Sender(Canoe) detect Error frame, will try again. Is it true?

Comment: When a CAN controller will detect an error during sending, it will abort sending and send the error frame. Default behavior is to re-try afterwards (unless error-off). Whether the message was triggered by the IG block or something else does not matter.

Comment: That's very kind of you.  Can controller will receive Re-try message absolutely?  Isn't possible to miss re-try message ?

Comment: For sure, any CAN controller could be configured differently. As said, the default behavior is to re-try, unless it goes to error passive. As said, the Controller or event the application might be configured differently.

Comment: I really want to thank you for your help .because of error frame, I  generally thought can controller can't receive 0x3d message. But 0x3d message is transmitted on canoe trace . I don't understand why canoe send 0x3d message. Already can controller send error frame because of 0x3d message. Is 0x3d message not lost ?

Comment: It is a TxError. I.e. an error during sending the message. Sending for the first time failed, so the CANoe tried again.

Comment: I appreciate your response and look forward to hearing from you again soon.